# Is there a way to disable mouse scrolling on a combobox in GTK/Gnome and Qt/KDE?

Tags: mouse, gtk, qt, scrolling

I'm scrolling a window content and it happens the mouse pointer place over a
combo box and it begins to scroll its content.
This is annoying. I experienced it in KDE and Gnome and I'm wondering
is there a workaround for this. There is no specific option in Kwin or Compiz
for this.

Comment: The effect of a mouse button on an application widget is up to the application, not up to the window manager.

Comment: there is a merge request in gnome source to fix this: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/merge_requests/4405